# using regex with javascript and getting variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I've not used regex in a while and I'm trying to use it in Javascript

I have a url string like /something/a/a123 and I only want to match strings that begin with /something and be able to get a and a123 as variables without splitting the string into an array.

Is that possible?

```
const r = /something/[a-z][A-Z]*/[a-z0-9][a-z0-0]*/
const s = r.exec('/something/a/a123');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
const r = /something\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z0-9]+)/i
const [_, a, b] = r.exec('/something/') || [,'','']
console.log(a, b)
```

Escape slashes and use round parens to capture those necessary regex parts.

Comment: ... for the sake of not failing due to `null` es possible return value for `exec` you might  consider changing your 2nd line to `const [_, a, b] = r.exec('/something/a/a123') || [];`

Comment: how can I exclude a particular word? eg. I want /something/a/a123 but I don't want /something/a/specificNonAlphaWord

Comment: @woopsie `/something\/([a-z]+)\/(?!word)([a-z0-9]+)/i`

Comment: is there a way to make it ONLY accept alphanums wihtout having to use (?!word)? \/([a-z0-9]+) something here to make sure it's only alpha? /i

Comment: @woopsie `/something\/([a-z]+)\/((?:[a-z]+\d|\d+[a-z])[\da-z]*)/i` might do.